# Single input fields using to four place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my previous code have Four Loan type. that four Loan type value load single input fields.  its my old UI.

```
<td width="20%">Type of Loan: </td>
    <td width="30%" >
      <input  type="radio" value="jumbo" name="loantype"  onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()"/>  Conforming/Jumbo<br />
      <input type="radio" value="fha" name="loantype" checked onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()"/>    FHA<br />
      <input type="radio" value="va" name="loantype" onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()" /> VA<br />
      <input type="radio" value="usda" name="loantype"  onClick="javascript:loanTypeChanged()" /> USDA<br />
    </td>
```

that code for the four loan type of code. that all loan type load the value single input fields

Upfront MIP

Now i new  Ui design four loan type have each input fields how to use this input fields to four loan each type?

this is my script:

```
function isNumeric(strString)
   //  check for valid numeric strings  
   {
   var strValidChars = "0123456789.-";
   var strChar;
   var blnResult = true;

   if (strString.length == 0) return false;

   //  test strString consists of valid characters listed above
   for (i = 0; i < strString.length && blnResult == true; i++)
      {
      strChar = strString.charAt(i);
      if (strValidChars.indexOf(strChar) == -1)
         {
          blnResult = false;
         }
      }
   return blnResult;
   }

function ficoChanged()
{
  //setDownPayment();
  getMIP("hh");
}

function loanTypeChanged()
{
  setDownPayment();
  getMIP("loantype"); //it must be set to loantype 
}

//always called by either change in loantype or change in fico 
function setDownPayment()
{
    if (userChangedDownPaymentPc_==true  || userChangedDownPaymentAmt_==true)
    {
        return;
    }
    //1. get selected loan type
    for (i=0;i<4;i++ )
    {
      if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['loantype'][i].checked==true)
        {
          var loantype_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.loantype[i].value;
          break;
        }
    }

    if (loantype_=="usda" || loantype_=="va")
    {
        document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=0;
    }       
    else if (loantype_=="fha")
    {
        document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=min_fha_down_payment;
    }
    else if (loantype_=="jumbo")
    {
        var ficorange_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements['ficorange'].value;
        var arr=ficorange_.split("-");
        if(arr[1] >= 720)
        document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=min_jumbo_down_payment_1;
        else
        document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value=min_jumbo_down_payment_2;
    }
}


  function purchasePriceAmountChanged(fromuser_)
  {
      getMIP("hh");
      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlypayment.value="";
  }

  function monthlyPaymentChanged(fromuser_)
  {

      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value="";
      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmippc.value="";
      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmipamt.value="";
      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymippc.value="";
      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymipamt.value="";
      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymippc.value="";
      document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymipamt.value="";

  }

  function downPaymentAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  {
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value="";         
     getMIP("hh");
    }
  }

  function downPaymentPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  {
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentpc.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value="";         
     getMIP("hh");
    }
  }

 //   todo : CHANGE IT, ITS NOT WORKING ANYMORE
  function getLoanAmount()
  {
    var purchaseprice_=0;
    var downpayment_=0;
    var loanamount_=-1;
    var hasloan=false;
    if(document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value!="")
      {
        downpayment_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.downpaymentamt.value;
      }
    else
      {
          hasloan=true;
      }
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value!="")
      {
         purchaseprice_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value;
      }
    else
      {
        hasloan=true;
      }

   if (hasloan==false)
      {
        loanamount_= purchaseprice_ - downpayment_ ;
      }

      return loanamount_;
  }


  function getPurchasePrice()
  {
     if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value!="")
      {
         purchaseprice_=document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.purchaseprice.value;
      }
      else
      {
         purchaseprice_=-1;
      }
    return purchaseprice_;
  }

  function upfrontMIPPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) else false
  {
    userChangedUpfrontMIP=fromuser_;
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmippc.value !="")
      {
       document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmipamt.value="";
      }
  }

  function upfrontMIPAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  {
     userChangedUpfrontMIP=fromuser_;
     if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmipamt.value !="")
      {
       document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.upfrontmippc.value="";
      }
  }

  function monthlyMIPPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) else false
  {
     userChangedMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
     if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymippc.value !="")
      {
       document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymipamt.value="";
      }
  }

  function monthlyMIPAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  {
     userChangedMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
     if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymipamt.value !="")
      {
       document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.monthlymippc.value="";
      }
  }

  function ssmonthlyMIPPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) else false
  {
     userChangedSSMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
     if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymippc.value !="")
      {
       document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymipamt.value="";
      }
  }

  function ssmonthlyMIPAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  {
     userChangedSSMonthlyMIP=fromuser_;
     if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymipamt.value !="")
      {
       document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.ssmonthlymippc.value="";
      }
  }

 function propertyTaxPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  {
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxpc.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxamt.value="";
    }
  }


 function propertyTaxAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxamt.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.propertytaxpc.value="";
    }
  }

 function hazardInsurancePcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  {
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsurancepc.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsuranceamt.value="";
    }
  }

 function hazardInsuranceAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsuranceamt.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.hazardinsurancepc.value="";
    }
  }

 function melloRoosAmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeeamt.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeepc.value="";
    }
  }  

 function melloRoosPcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeepc.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.melloroosfeeamt.value="";
    }
  }     

 function other1PcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1pc.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1amt.value="";
    }
  } 

 function other1AmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1amt.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other1pc.value="";
    }
  }       

 function other2PcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2pc.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2amt.value="";
    }
  } 

 function other2AmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2amt.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other2pc.value="";
    }
  }

 function other3PcChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3pc.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3amt.value="";
    }
  } 

 function other3AmountChanged(fromuser_)//true (if user changed  it) or false
  { 
    if (document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3amt.value!="")
    {
     document.forms['frmCalculator'].elements.other3pc.value="";
    }
  }

  function secondsChanged()
  {
    getMIP("hh");
  }
```

please Help me ? i have  tired copy inputs paste  four place its showing same value four place ?

Comment: You can use `isNaN` method to check if a string is numeric or not. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Please help us understand your question.

Comment: In my previous design  have four  radio button option .if select  radio value change single input for four radio button. now my new  design  four radio button have  separate input fields. how to use single input fields to four input fields ?

Comment: I am starting to understand. Can you provide markup for the four input fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage jQuery to shrink your code and make it more concise.

```js
$('input[name=loantype]').on('change', function() {
    var loanAmount = +$(this).closest('tr').prev().find('input[name=' + this.value + ']').val();
    console.log( this.value, loanAmount );
    //other code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Loan Values: </td>
    <td>Jumbo: <input name="jumbo" type="number"/></td>
    <td>FHA: <input name="fha" type="number"/></td>  
    <td>VA: <input name="va" type="number"/></td>
    <td>USDA: <input name="usda" type="number"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="20%">Type of Loan: </td>
      <td><input  type="radio" value="jumbo" name="loantype"/>  Conforming/Jumbo</td>
      <td><input type="radio" value="fha" name="loantype"/>    FHA</td>
      <td><input type="radio" value="va" name="loantype"/> VA</td>
      <td><input type="radio" value="usda" name="loantype"/> USDA</td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```